# android layout: dynamic margin in LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, layout

The scenario:

10 buttons in an linear layout using layoutweight: 1

The result i want:

The buttons should fill the linear layout by adapting their margin.

Failed attempt:

I tried setting, for the linear layout, the attribute weightsum: 11 (number of buttons + 1) in the   hope that the remaining 11 - 10 would be used as a margin divided to all the buttons (1/10 margin for each button)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try a `ConstraintLayout`, if you constraint all buttons to each other they will spread out evenly inside the `ViewPort`.

Top<-B1<->B2<->B3...B10->Bottom